# How to clone Nhibernate QueryOver without conditions?

Tags: nhibernate, clone, queryover

I have the following QueryOver:

```
var q = Session.QueryOver<CostCenter>().Where(c => c.PrimeCompany.Id == idPrimeCompany);
```

I need to clone the QueryOver but without the "where clausule". Is this possible?

Comment: You can clone it fully with `Clone()`... but cloning it in parts... Mmmmh...

Comment: I used Clone() but, how you said, return fully. =/

Comment: I don't think there is a "legal" way to remove a restriction from a `QueryOver` (or from a `ICriteria` in general, that is the base of `QueryOver`). Something with reflection could be built, but I wouldn't touch it with a 40-feet pole. Remove seems to be the opposite problem of what you want, but `Clone() + Remove()` would be the perfect solution :-)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Could you clone the query *before* adding the where clause?

Comment: I have a method that receives as parameter a QueryOver. With it, i build a list with current QueryOver, and i need to count rows without the current Criteria, counting all rows.

Answer (score 2):

use the root entity (class used in the call of session.QueryOver<>) and build a new query

```
var roottype = theQueryOver.UnderlyingCriteria.GetRootEntityTypeIfAvailable();

var totalCount = session.CreatCriteria(roottype).SetProjection(Projections.RowCount()).UniqueReasult<long>();
```

Comment: This won't save Join(s), right? In the example given it will only retrieve `typeof(CostCenter)`

Comment: There were no joins in the question. Do you need to count the rootobjects or also the rows created by the cartesian product of joins? If the latter then why?

Comment: No, but the point is that you should explain what `GetRootEntityTypeIfAvailable` does...

Comment: Added the info that it will get the rootentity which is typeof(CostCenter) in your example.